# Can someone please explain in great detail how Advanced Locomotion V4 works

Tags: unreal-engine4

Please correct my understanding.

Advanced Locomotion uses AnimModifiers, Blueprints, Blendspaces, Creates curves programmatically and applies them. It stores alot of the functionalities inside functions which you cannot open to see how it works. Which also means it cannot be extracted to be used in a macro?

Ben

Comment: This would be a question for the author: https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/advanced-locomotion-system-v1/questions